# When use IEnumerable in view client side validation is not working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, unobtrusive-validation

I am passing List from Model to view , so I specified in view like this 
IEnumerable. In this situation Client side validation is not firing

View :

```
@model  IEnumerable<ShoppingCart.Models.ShoppingClass>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Display";

}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.Label("BrandName")
            </td>
            <td>@Html.TextBox("BrandName")
                <div>
                    @Html.ValidationMessage("BrandName")</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Search" name="Search" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code? Otherwise, all we can say is sprinkle some fairy dust on your keyboard to fix the issue..

Comment: @raj2sekar1 if you are reposting a question, pls consider deleting your [old same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11772229/1182982)

Answer (score 1):

What you've written is wrong.

You're got the view strongly typed but then you're not using the strongly typed properties or validation messages. Also, you've got the validation summary outside the form.. which won't work.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

Then, you'll need to do something like this:

```
<table>
    @foreach (ShoppingClass shoppingClass in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.BrandName)
        </td>
        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.BrandName)
            <div>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.BrandName)</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Search" name="Search" />
```

I'm not sure why you have a Search button for every item that goes to the same controller and action.. but I'll leave that for you to figure out.